# How can I perform this Laravel project downloaded from Github?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I am pretty new in **PHP** and absolutly new in **Laravel** (I came from Java) and I have the following doubt.

I am trying to use this implemented example from GitHub to obtain a page containing a **reCaptcha**:

https://github.com/Waavi/recaptcha

So I have clone this repository on my local system.

Then, as explained, I have add the **"waavi/recaptcha": "1.0.x"** reference into the **require** section of the **composer.json** file, that became:

```
"require": {
    "illuminate/support": "^5.1",
    "illuminate/config": "^5.1"
    "waavi/recaptcha": "1.0.x"
},
```

Ok, now what have I to do to start my application? (I think that before start I have to run composer in some way to download all the dependency of this Laravel project). What have I to do?

Comment: https://adamcod.es/2013/03/07/composer-install-vs-composer-update.html

Comment: Delete any `composer.lock`, after that you need to run `composer install`to install your dependencies.

Comment: The README file explains that pretty well. Read carefully the section Instalation and Setup.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you cloned the recaptcha repository, but don't actually have a Laravel install.

I would suggest reading the Laravel Homestead Setup explained here:

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead

Then once you have a Laravel Install find the composer.json in that dir:

> your/install/directory/composer.json

Then add the required dependency to the "require" section as you did:

> "waavi/recaptcha": "1.0.x"

Then run a composer update from that directory:

> composer update

This should install the recaptcha dependency to your vendor/ folder.  After that, it looks like there are a few more install instructions from the recaptcha repository that you should make sure to complete.

Comment: Agreed.  If you are new to Laravel, follow the documentation for homestead above or if you are familiar with VMs, just follow the install directions [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4).  Once you have a Laravel application installed, you really only need to `cd` into that directory and run `composer require waavi/recaptcha 1.0.x` which will not only install it but add it to your composer.json.